# image preloader in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this code but i dont know what to do next..

```
var toBeInsertedToAS = "";

for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
{
    $('<img />')
    .attr('src','imgUrl_'+j+'.png')
    .load(function(){                
        toBeInsertedToAS += $(this).attr('src')+"|";                          
    });
    theSetDataCount++;
}    
alert(toBeInsertedToAS);
```

i just want to have this output..

> imgUrl_1.png|imgUrl_2.png|imgUrl_3.png|etc...

but as what i can see, after the loop, there's no output.. maybe because it goes to alert(toBeInsertedToAS) without loading the pictures completely.. i just want to completely load the pictures first before it will execute the alert..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange it a bit, like this:

```
var toBeInsertedToAS = [], theSetDataCount = 0;

for(j=1;j<=10;j++)
{
    $('<img />').one('load', function(){
                 toBeInsertedToAS.push(this.src);
                 if(toBeInsertedToAS.length == theSetDataCount)
                     alert(toBeInsertedToAS.join('|'));
              }).attr('src','imgUrl_'+j+'.png')
                .each(function() {
                  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
              });
    theSetDataCount++;
}
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/tFgZK/), this demo loads images from http://dummyimage.com/ as a source.

The [`load` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) happens when the image loads, not a synchronous thing, though it will be instant if it's from cache. From cache also won't fire the `load` event in some browsers...we're manually handling that with the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) ensures it only runs once, not affecting our count in a funny way.

The key here is to fire the `alert()` (or any other function) when the last `load` handler runs.

Comment: thank you sir.. that solves my problem.. 

anyway, can i ask for the explanation for this var declaration?

    var toBeInsertedToAS = [], theSetDataCount = 0;

Comment: ahh.. sir.. how about instead of alert(toBeInsertedToAS.join('|'));

i will put the result first to a variable// then alert after the for loop// ?)

like for(j=1;j<=10;j++){the code here that assigns the result to newVariable}alert(newVariable);

Comment: because/.. all that code above.. the whole for loop, it still has the loop outside that loop.. so, maybe, the first result for that code must be put to a newVariable[0].. then next outside loop, the second result will be put to the newVariable[1]//

is that posible  sir?

Comment: @vrynxzent - You can create multiple variables with a comma instead of `var ` each time, so it's equal to  `var toBeInsertedToAS = []; var theSetDataCount = 0;`, making an empty array and int to use.  If you put this inside a loop (that's a closure, say `.each()`), **including** the variables, they'll be per-loop and you can re-use them.